# Implement serializable in Spring Boot Entity Class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Please what does implementing Serializable interface do to an entity class in spring boot data JPA. what are the consequences of not implementing the interface as well.

Comment: Yes, I got the answer from someone else already. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

First you know about serialization.. **This will help you when u need to implement serializable or not**...

> Actually, you should not be "generating" serial version UIDs. It is a
>   dumb "feature" that stems from the general misunderstanding of how
>   that ID is used by Java. You should be giving these IDs meaningful,
>   readable values, e.g. starting with 1L, and incrementing them each
>   time you think the new version of the class should render all previous
>   versions (that might be previously serialized) obsolete. All utilities
>   that generate such IDs basically do what the JVM does when the ID is
>   not defined: they generate the value based on the content of the class
>   file, hence coming up with unreadable meaningless long integers. If
>   you want each and every version of your class to be distinct (in the
>   eyes of the JVM) then you should not even specify the serialVersionUID
>   value isnce the JVM will produce one on the fly, and the value of each
>   version of your class will be unique. The purpose of defining that
>   value explicitly is to tell the serialization mechanism to treat
>   different versions of the class that have the same SVUID as if they
>   are the same, e.g. not to reject the older serialized versions. So, if
>   you define the ID and never change it (and I assume that's what you do
>   since you rely on the auto-generation, and you probably never
>   re-generate your IDs) you are ensuring that all - even absolutely
>   different - versions of your class will be considered the same by the
>   serialization mechanism. Is that what you want? If not, and if you
>   indeed want to have control over how your objects are recognized, you
>   should be using simple values that you yourself can understand and
>   easily update when you decide that the class has changed
>   significantly. Having a 23-digit value does not help at all.